# Is there any complete solution for deploying/updating ASP.NET MVC website via self webpage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, web-deployment

I face some strange situation about deploying ASP.NET MVC 3 application to IIS 6 web server. Server admin does not allow me to directly connect to her server via FTP, web-based management or any remote protocol from external network. So I need to use intranet to copy and paste updated files to her shared folder of my web application.

She told that some other project use their page to update/deploy website. I know. It's possible for interpreter language like PHP. But for ASP.NET MVC, we need to change current application DLL when we update application.

How to update/deploy new version of website by using .NET technology in ASP.NET MVC3 website? The following items are all my concerns about this.

1. This tool must be web-based management that in the same website.
2. Security - It is public web application, so we need to make sure no one else to access to this update tool without my authority.
3. Stable - Even I update website that cause fatal error(like error in web.config file). I still can access to this update tool.
4. Speed – I able to handle a ton of AJAX request for uploading file.
   Thanks,

PS. I don't require full source code for doing this. But I want detailed idea or/and example that can solve my request.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for solutions to this problem too... just found this but haven't had a chance to try it yet: http://octopusdeploy.com/